# react / redux burger menu cannot open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am confused by this line in the documentation for redux-burger-menu:

https://negomi.github.io/redux-burger-menu/

Decorate your menu component:

// Menu.js

```
  import {slide as Menu} from 'react-burger-menu';
  import {decorator as reduxBurgerMenu} from 'redux-burger-menu';

  export default reduxBurgerMenu(Menu);
```

The component you export from the above file can then be used just like react-burger-menu.

How do I import this component and use it just like react-burger-menu?

I have a NarrativeMenu here:

```
class NarrativeMenu extends React.Component {
showSettings(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

render() {
    return (
          <Menu>
            <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
            <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
            <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            <a onClick={ this.showSettings } className="menu-item--small" href="">Settings</a>
          </Menu>
    );
}
}
```

How can I use it with redux burger menu?

Answer (score 3):

I also found it a bit confusing. I made it work like this:

Menu.js:

```
import {slide as Menu} from 'react-burger-menu';
import {decorator as reduxBurgerMenu} from 'redux-burger-menu';

const ReduxBurgerMenu = reduxBurgerMenu(Menu);

export default ReduxBurgerMenu;
```

ExampleMenu.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReduxBurgerMenu from './Menu';

class ExampleMenu extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <ReduxBurgerMenu isOpen={ this.props.isOpen }>
                <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
                <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
                <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </ReduxBurgerMenu>
        );
    }
}

export default ExampleMenu;
```

and then use it like this:

```
import ExampleMenu from 'ExampleMenu'

...

    render () {
        return (
            <div id="outer-container">
                <Header />
                <ExampleMenu pageWrapId={"page-wrap"} outerContainerId={"outer-container"} />
                <div id="page-wrap">

                ...

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

...
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify **Jan Caals** example.

ExampleMenu.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {slide as Menu} from 'react-burger-menu';
import {decorator as reduxBurgerMenu} from 'redux-burger-menu';

const ReduxBurgerMenu = reduxBurgerMenu(Menu);

class ExampleMenu extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <ReduxBurgerMenu isOpen={ this.props.isOpen }>
                <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
                <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
                <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </ReduxBurgerMenu>
        );
    }
}

export default ExampleMenu;
```